# Merge migrations from two different servers

Tags: database, api, relational-database, versioning, backend

I'm working on a project that has two separate versions of the API, v1, and v2 because they wanted to migrate from Javascript to Typescript. Both versions use the same database.

Recently I'm having some trouble as one part of the migrations are in the v1, and the most recent updates are on version v2. I would like to have all the migration in the same place, how can this be done?

One of the problems I'm facing, for example, is that I would like to set up an in-memory DB for tests, but as I don't have all the migrations in v2 I can't do this.

Tech stack used in v1: javascript, node, sequelize.

Tech stack used in v2: typescript, node, typeorm.

Comment: Is there any chance you will ever even possibly roll back the migrations stored in the V1 codebase? If not, just baseline yourself at the start of the V2 codebase.

Answer (score 1):

Store the database source control separate from the api. If you only have one database don't store two versions of it, this will only ever cause issues. If you aren't sure you can combine existing migrations it's time to re-script your database from production and start over.